# Why remove the letter "C" before ${expression} causes error?

Tags: robotframework

I am using Python-RF framework with the example below. I scanned the file
"C" is considered as "". If in the robot file I remove the letter C before the ${expression}, it causes error

Original:

```
Test Template     Calculate
Library           CalculatorLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***    Expression    Expected
Addition              12 + 2 + 2    16
                      2 + -3        -1

*** Keywords ***
Calculate
    [Arguments]    ${expression}    ${expected}
    Push buttons    C${expression}=
    Result should be    ${expected}
```

Changed:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Additions             12 + 2 + 2    16
                      2 + -3        -1


*** Keywords ***
Calculate
    [Arguments]    ${expression}    ${expected}
    Push buttons    ${expression}=
    Result should be    ${expected}
```

There is an error " 159 != -1". Everyone can share your ideas what wrong it is?

Library file:
https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/robotdemo/src/51f472687b6a46e88b7c179423f0f336e19497fc/CalculatorLibrary.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/robotdemo/src/51f472687b6a46e88b7c179423f0f336e19497fc/calculator.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to post the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Without "C":**

After your first test case `${expression}` is "16". Then you put "2" at the end of it, now `${expression}` is "162". Then you substract 3 from it which gives you 159 and this is what you see in the error.

**With "C":**

Using "C" you set `${expression}` to "" (empty string) and then you calculate "2-3" which gives you correct "-1".